# Mysql Like query not match the record

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

I am trying to match the record with the like operator. I need to get this record match with the title.
[image]

But the title has lots of quotes so the operator not matching the record.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_product_library WHERE tittle LIKE 'dsdasd\"ddd | sdfsdf\'ss%'
```

Mysql return zero records
[image]

Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: Stored string contains single and double quotes? Perhaps REPLACE them and test.

Comment: `"` should not be in your query

Comment: the table has lots of records .so cant replaces the quotes for all records.

Comment: Think it more to do with the \'s, try with `SELECT * FROM wp_product_library WHERE tittle LIKE 'dsdasd\\\\\"ddd | sdfsdf\\\\\'ss%'`

Comment: I can't find reference for `|` in the `LIKE` clause.  Should be `LIKE 'x' OR LIKE 'y'`.  Maybe you need https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like

Comment: Show the value(s) which must match your pattern.

Comment: I want which title has `sdfsdf\'ss`